# ¿Cómo se refleja en la escritura cuando una persona interrumpe a otra en un diálogo?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación

Como ya sabemos todos, en español se usan los puntos suspensivos (...) con el siguiente propósito, [como recoge el DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=puntos%20suspensivos):

> Para señalar la interrupción voluntaria de un discurso cuyo final se da por conocido o sobrentendido por el interlocutor.

Sin embargo, ¿qué pasa si esa interrupción es involuntaria? ¿Cómo se refleja en la escritura el que una persona interrumpa a otra?

En ocasiones he visto en subtítulos de películas y series el uso del guion con este propósito:

> —Pues en mi opinión creo que debe-
>   —¿Tú qué vas a opinar?

En este caso se entiende que la segunda persona ha empezado a hablar antes de que la primera terminara, cortando su diálogo sin dejarle acabar. No es algo que reflejen los puntos suspensivos, ya que si el diálogo fuera así

> —Pues en mi opinión creo que debe...
>   —¿Tú qué vas a opinar?

lo que yo entiendo es que la primera ha perdido el hilo del discurso y la segunda al ver que el primero no acaba es cuando arranca a hablar.

¿Es correcto ese uso del guión? ¿O se debería reflejar la interrupción en el diálogo añadiendo una explicación? Tal que así:

> —Pues en mi opinión creo que debe...
>   —¿Tú qué vas a opinar? —dijo, interrumpiendo a su colega.

Comment: Interesante dilema. Yo apostaría por enfatizar la referencia a la interrupción, más que nada porque los puntos suspensivos pueden tener otras connotaciones, como que la persona alarga una frase enigmáticamente o similares. Veo cierto debate al respecto en los comentarios a [Estructura de los diálogos](http://reglas-escritura.blogspot.com.es/2007/10/estructura-de-los-dilogos.html)

Answer (score 8):

[Preguntada a la RAE](https://twitter.com/charliealejo/status/854669413785665537) al respecto en Twitter si se usan los puntos suspensivos también para las interrupciones involuntarias del discurso. Me encanta la devoción que emplean para responder a todo el mundo. En una primera aproximación, [su respuesta fue la siguiente](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/854977788570370048):

> También. Se usan en el discurso interrumpido y al reanudarlo después. El inciso «interrumpe fulano» es muy útil.

Es decir, validan la opción de añadir un inciso tal y como se refleja en mi último ejemplo. Tratando de profundizar un poco más, les pregunté [qué pasa cuando no es posible insertar incisos](https://twitter.com/charliealejo/status/854980987863920640), como es el caso de los subtítulos. [Su nueva respuesta fue](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/855015288336773121):

> También al redactar subtítulos: «—Me dij... —¡Cállate! —... Es que me dijo que... —¡He dicho que te calles!».

Por tanto, definitivamente parece que sí, que los puntos suspensivos también se usan para interrupciones involuntarias del discurso.

Comment: ¡Caramba! O sea que _—Me dij..._ salto de línea _—¡Cállate!_ es válido. Lo que se aprende por aquí...

Answer (score 3):

Hay un libro que se llama "Self-editing for fiction writers" de Renni Browne y Dave King (ambos editores en una gran editorial estadounidense), desconozco si está traducido en español, diría que no. Es una biblia para los escritores por el mundo, dicen que es un libro que todos los escritores lo deberían tener en casa.
En referencia a los comentarios anteriores.

1. Este libro condena el inciso "—le interrumpió Pepe." Lo justifican con que, si necesitas poner "le interrumpió él" para que quede claro, es que tu dialogo falla. Si el texto, el subtexto y el contexto de tu dialogo están bien escritos, no necesitarías explicarle al lector que un personaje ha interrumpido al otro.
2. También en este libro, recomiendan encarecidamente utilizar la raya (no el guion) para indicar interrupción y dejar los puntos suspensivos para cuando la conversación se interrumpe por motivos diferentes a la mala educación del interlocutor, como por ejemplo: cuando el personaje se le olvida de qué estaba hablando, se da cuenta en medio de la frase que sería mejor no decir lo que estaba a punto de decir, intenta encontrar la palabra correcta para continuar, etc. Incluso, recomiendan utilizar los puntos suspensivos para las escenas en las que un personaje que posee el punto de vista en dicha escena escucha a otro personaje hablar por el teléfono y, obviamente, como el personaje que habla no es el del punto de vista, el lector no debería escuchar lo que se dice en el otro lado de la línea (buena manera de ocultarle información al lector; si es imprescindible que el lector "escuche" la otra parte de la conversación, habrá que encender el altavoz del móvil :D ). En estos casos, la replica de un personaje podría terminar con puntos suspensivos para indicar el silencio que tiene lugar mientras está hablando el interlocutor al otro lado de la línea (al que no escuchamos).
3. Bien diferenciadas las interrupciones cometidas por otros personajes (terminadas con raya) de las demás (terminadas con puntos suspensivos), queda totalmente innecesaria la acotación “le interrumpió él”.
   Ahora bien, quiero que conste, esto es lo aceptado en la escuela estadounidense de escritura creativa y tampoco es la norma indicada en la puntuación de la lengua inglesa. Los editores de este país lo han aceptado para mejorar la comprensión en la lectura.